# Laravel Middleware Error - Call to a member function isBasic() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check user type when they log in and apply function

In my `middleware`, I have this code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($user->isBasic()) {
        $previous_session = $user->session_id;

        if ($previous_session) {
            \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
        }

        Auth::user()->session_id = \Session::getId();
        Auth::user()->save();
        return redirect(route('home'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

In my `User model`, I have this

```
public function isBasic()
{
    return $this->role=='basic';
}
```

I have already registered the middleware in Kernel

```
'basic' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSession::class,
```

And I passed it to my LoginController like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('basic');
}
```

But when it tried to visit the login controller, it says

> Call to a member function isBasic() on null

I am a  beginner in Laravel and I don't know what to do

Comment: "before login" would mean there is no authenticated user yet, because they haven't logged in, so what would you be checking since there is no user to check?

Comment: I am new in Laravel, so what I want is to be able to check while they log in, if user type is basic, the function in the middleware should be called. I know I am doing something wrong, that's why I came here for help. I tried using the function in controller, but it applies to all user type

Comment: this is something you would have to check in the login functionality itself, something like the `authenticated` method that gets called **after** they are logged in in the LoginController

Comment: you could use   $this->middleware('basic')->except([''showLoginForm' , 'login']); you are checking for authenticated user while no user has login to your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good candidate for the `authenticated` method of the `LoginController` which gets called **after** a user has logged in.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->isBasic()) {
        $previous_session = $user->session_id;

        if ($previous_session) {
            $request->session()->getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
        }

        $user->session_id = $requset->session()->getId();
        $user->save();

        // do these specific users need to be redirected to somewhere special?
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

You could even listen for the Auth events if you wanted to, as long as its not a queued listener.

Comment: yeah this should have been the correct way for the OP's scenario rather than going for the middleware

Comment: i thought this method was documented still but it doesn't seem to be in the docs at the moment

Answer (score 1):

you should use [Auth::check()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) to determine if user is authenticated or not

in your middleware, you are doing

```
 $user = Auth::user();
    if ($user->isBasic()) {...}
```

In this part, if the user is not authenticated then the $user will have `null` value
you will have to check if the user is authenticated or not.

Eg:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check()) { //check if the user is logged in or not
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user->isBasic()) {
            $previous_session = $user->session_id;

            if ($previous_session) {
                \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
            }

            Auth::user()->session_id = \Session::getId();
            Auth::user()->save();
            return redirect(route('home'));
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve my problem using your code in my controller. Thank.s